# Horizontal List View inside Stack is not scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
Stack(
 childern:[
    Positioned(
              bottom: 0,
           child: SizedBox(height:80,width:1000,
              child: ListView(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      width: 230,
                      height: 30,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10),
                      child: TextField(),
                  !isTyping
                      ? Expanded(
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35),
                            child: Row(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "images/haha.png",
                                    width: 36,
                                    height: 36,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "images/wow.png",
                                    width: 36,
                                    height: 36,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
                                  child: Image.asset(
                                    "images/love.png",
                                    width: 36,
                                    height: 36,
                                  ),
                                ), 
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      : Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 35.h),
                          child: CircleAvatar(
                            radius: 20,
                            backgroundColor: MyApp.blueColor,
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.send,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                ],
              ),
            )
    ]
)
```

So I have a list view inside stack which consists of **TextField** and **Row** of widgets. I want to make those **scroll horizontally** but not able to do.
Where did I missed it?

I have tried using Sized box to bound the ListView but it didnt provide scrollable feature.

Comment: Can you see elements of the stack on screen? Because `childern` is wrongly written.

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan After using sized box I can see them but it doesnt make it scrollable. Help me to make them visible as well as scrollable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try wrap your ListView with `LimitedBox()` and set `maxHeight` and `maxWidth`

Answer (score 0):

One of these two things might help you get it back to scrolling.

1. Set Shrink wrap to true:

   ```
      shrinkWrap: true,
   ```
2. Set      physics to NeverScrollableScrollPhysics because it may be usefull if the lisview is wrapped in another LisView.

   ```
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
   ```

Let me know if it doesnt help.

Comment: It didnt worked. I have updated the code where I have used sized box. It shows the element but not able to scroll

Comment: try removing the positioned, i guess you do not really need it

Comment: actually there are other widgets too in stack so I used positioned here